# How to prevent the renaming of a column and table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, rename

I want to protect a database in the following way:

- Tables should be protected against drops and renames
- Columns should be protected against drops and renames
- Adding tables and columns is permitted

To put this into context: it's a `vocabularies` database (look-up tables) that will be the central master copy, to be distributed to other databases (on the same server and in the future to other servers (even non SQL server systems).

Adding tables and columns can be handled in a way that the client databases can continue to work and get the updates when they appear. Dropping tables and columns on the other hand will have to be handled in a different, orchestrated) way.

I created a DDL trigger to lock the drops of tables and columns, that was the easy part.
Unfortunately, renaming tables and columns are handled, it seems, by the `sp_rename` procedure and this procedure uses the following construct:

```
EXEC %%Object(ID = @objid).SetName(Name = @newname)
```

This isn't picked up by the DDL trigger. Is there any way of making sure tables and columns are NOT renamed?

Comment: What about to create users and logins and grand right permissions to each one?  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/23/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-security-a-primer/

Comment: Well, yes, after posting this question, that route popped into my mind as well. Thing is: I also want to safeguard myself, in a DBA context against renaming tables and columns. I hoped that there is a way to have these %%object actions be detected by the DDL trigger as well, that would make it easier since I'd be blocked when the DDL trigger is active, but can disable the trigger temporarily whenever the namechange has been planned and taken into account by the client databases.

Comment: @user1746581 why not create yourself a lower privilege account, and only use the admin account when it is needed?

Answer (score 0):

For each table, create a view with schemabinding as the following code demonstrates:

```
CREATE VIEW PreventDropOnT1
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT Col1, Col2
    FROM T1
```